# Using a Python method from another class without self

Tags: python

Hello i am pretty new in python and i have some problems with the oop. I am used to java where you can easily acces methods from other classes over the object/instance.

I am trying the following thing:

```
class Tello:
    localIP = ''
    # port = 9000
    localPort = 8890
    localAddr = (localIP, localPort)
    telloIP = '192.168.10.1'
    telloPort = 8889

    sockCommand = None
    sockListen = None
    telloAddress = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.sockCommand = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.telloAddress = (self.telloIP, self.telloPort)
        self.sockCommand.bind(self.localAddr)
...
...

   def telMove(self, direction, distance):
        self.sockCommand.sendto(("%s %s" % (direction, distance)).encode(encoding="utf-8"), self.telloAddress)

from tello import Tello as drone
class Form(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        # controlling vars
        self.distance = 3.48
        self.degree = 30
        self.stream = 0
...
....
 def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == Qt.Key_W:
            print("[*] tello moving up")
            drone.telMove(dir.UP, self.distance)
        # TODO: MOVE DOWN
```

But i am not able to call the method telMove() because i need to pass the self argument. What is the way to solve it? I thought about making  a function, but i would have problems with accesing the socket and also i prefare using methods since telMove() is a part of a class

I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/A703980/PycharmProjects/tello/testing.py", line 83, in keyPressEvent
    drone.telMove(direction=dir.UP, distance=self.distance)
TypeError: telMove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: What is `drone` supposed to be? `self` is provided implicitly as the instance before the dot. When calling a method on an *instance* `inst.foo(bar)` essentially desugars to `type(inst).foo(inst, bar)` (though the details are more complicated).

Comment: i use from tello import Tello as drone

Comment: Ah yes I seem that's the error: `Tello` is a class, by importing it as `drone` you're just trying to call an instance method on a class. You should `from tello import Tello` then define drone as `drone = Trello()`. That way you have a proper instance and can call methods on that. Though your socket management doesn't make much sense here: `sock.bind` is used to configure a server socket (waiting for connections), you don't send or recv on a server socket, you accept() on it then work with the connection socket that hands out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported `drone` as a class defintion, not as an object. It should be:

```
from tello import Tello
drone = Tello()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/A703980/PycharmProjects/tello/testing.py", line 83, in keyPressEvent
    drone.telMove(direction=dir.UP, distance=self.distance)
TypeError: telMove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: My problem is, that in order to call the method telMove() from the class Form i need to pass an argument for self. But i dont know what to pass at this moment because i dont understand how this works at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem if you do `from tello import Tello as drone` is that `drone` will be the class "Tello" itself, and not an instance of this class "Tello"

You need to first import the class "Tello", then create an instance that you call `drone` :

```
from tello import Tello # import the class so you can use it
...
drone = Tello() # drone is now an instance of the class Tello
...
drone.telMove(dir.UP, self.distance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove
`from tello import Tello as drone`

write

`from tello import Tello`

`drone = Tello()`

when you did `from tello import Tello as drone`: You imported Tello class from tello module and renamed it to drone. And you are trying to use it's method from class itself.You should use method from object not class.

Your mistake in simple example:

```
class Hello:
    def greet(self):
        print('Hello')
```

What you're doing is,

```
Hello.greet() #Error!
```

What you should do,

```
obj = Hello()

obj.greet()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.